# Add event handler to button in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, events, button

I created a button in c++ as follows:

```
HWND btn = CreateWindow(
    "BUTTON",
    "OK",
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
    10,
    10,
    100, 
    100,
    hWnd, 
    NULL, 
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
    NULL);
```

The button is displayed in the main window (hWnd) but I don't know how or where to give it an event handler. Any help please?

Comment: Before anyone tries to answer, some advice -- Don't try and write Windows API code without a good book or reference handy.   The API is much too complex to fly blind writing code. There are several books, references, etc. showing exactly how to create a window and add event handlers.

Comment: in winapi terms it's c not c++. second: this is not  script .You cant just paste it and run.

Comment: select something else to begin with. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640330/winapi-bn-clicked-how-to-identify-which-button-was-clicked#20640498

Comment: Start [here](http://winprog.org/tutorial/) then get [Petzold's](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Fifth-Developer-Reference/dp/157231995X) book. As for your specific question, you need to handle [WM_COMMAND message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 7):

There are three ways to detect the button being clicked.

1. The preferred approach is to add a [`WM_COMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591.aspx) handler to the window procedure of the button's parent window.  When the button is clicked, it sends a [`BN_CLICKED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825.aspx) notification to its parent window.  This is described in the MSDN documentation for buttons:

   [Handling Messages from a Button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775941.aspx#handling_button_messages)

   [Notification Messages from Buttons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775941.aspx#notifications_from_buttons)
2. If you are adding the button to a parent window that you do not own, you can subclass the parent window using [`SetWindowsLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) or [`SetWindowSubClass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx), and then you can handle messages that are sent to it, such as `BN_CLICKED`.  This only works if the subclassing code runs in the same thread that owns the parent window.

   Alternatively, you can subclass the button itself and handle keyboard and mouse messages instead.
3. Another option is to set an event hook using [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) asking to receive `EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED` events.  In the [event callback procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373885.aspx), the provided `hwnd`, `ID`, and `idChild` parameters will identify the control that is being invoked, such as a clicked button.

Answer (score 3):

When the button is clicked, it sends a [`BN_CLICKED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825.aspx) notification message (carried by the [`WM_COMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591.aspx) message) to its parent window.  The `BN_CLICKED` notification code is in the `HIWORD` of the `wParam` of the message.  The `LOWORD` of the `wParam` of the message has the ID of the button.  The `lParam` of the message has the `HWND` of the button.  This is all in the online Windows docs.  Google for `BN_CLICKED`.

Consider this pseudo code... it's from memory.  Basically, add the stuff inside the `WM_COMMAND` case to the window procedure that you already have:

```
LRESULT WINAPI YourWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
   switch (nMsg)
   {
      case WM_COMMAND:
      {
         switch (HIWORD(wp))
         {
            case BN_CLICKED:
            {
               switch (LOWORD(wp))
               {
                  case IDC_BUTTON1: // or whatever the ID of your button is...
                  {
                     // do stuff for button...
                     break;
                  }
               }
               break;
            }
         }
         break;
      }

      default:
         return DefWindowProc(hWnd, nMsg, wp, lp);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second-to-last parameter, type (HMENU)1

in the WNDPROC:

```
switch (uMsg)
{
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam)
        {
            case 1:
                // Code
        }
}
```